# Dynamically resize text in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/zg2zgna5/1/) . I am dynamically changing the text font to fix in the div. It is working fine. My text is in span, but I do not want to use span. If I remove the span then it stops working. I even changed my function from.

```
var ourText = $('span:visible:first', this);
```

to

```
 var ourText = $(targetid, this);
```

i want to use like this

```
 <h1  id="h1" class='jtextfill'>
    Sample 
</h1>
<h2 id="h2"  class='jtextfill2' >
   aaSamp sfd sdfsf sfsddffds ss ssf fsdf sdf sfs fsdfs sdfsdf sdf sdfsfsfsdfsdfsf sdf sfsf sfs sf sf sd  sfsf sfsdsfd sfdfdf a ada  adf ad adasda a adsa s sfzz
</h2>
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery selectors are malformed: write `$( "#"+targetid )` instead of `$(targetid)`. The latter construct references *tags* corresponding to the cntent of the parameter `targetid` - to reference ids, you have to prefix the id with the literal `#`. Note that this only applies to jquery and css selectors, in particular not to the argument of `getElementById`.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/snza8vhw/1/) (Everything said applies to `ourText = $('#'+targetid, this);` too, of course).

Update:
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/dpom33bh/6/) contains streamlined code.

I do not see how you could dispense of the 'span' element: to get height and width of the text you need an element to read the height/width attribute from. But you also need the container that defines the viewport into which you want to fit your text.

Comment: I streamlined the code and I think the result is closer to your intent.